# Got error when inserting new records (undefined id error in php)

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql, ajax

When passing the ID for one `php` page into another `php` page using the REQUEST method it will working fine as well as display the appropriate data in table.

On the other hand, whenever inserting new data here it will shows the undefined index error messages all the time.

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\job_working_stat.php on line 191
```

**Here is my php and html code:**

*Ordersform.php Page:*

```
$ord_id=$row[id];
<a href='edit/job_status.php?id=$ord_id'>
</a>
```

*job_working_stat.php:*

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id']))
    {
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $query="select * from new_order where id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $getrefno=$row['job_ref_no'];
    $getrefdate=$row['job_order_date'];
    echo'<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="id-form">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="normal_list3">
    <td width="30%">Ref.No</td>
    <td width="70%"> '.$getrefno.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normal_list3"><td>Order Date</td>
    <td width="70%"> '.$getrefdate.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="updateform"></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>';
    
    if(isset($_POST['updateform']))
    {

    **$id=$_REQUEST['id'];**   -> problem line 
    $query="select * from new_order where id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $getrefno=$row['job_ref_no'];
    $getrefdate=$row['job_order_date'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO order_history (job_ref_no, job_order_date)
        VALUES ('.$getrefno.','.$getrefdate.')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error($db), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, div doesn't have `href` that should be `a` tag . Also , which line is  `191` ?

Comment: @Swati hi swathi i updated the code. can you pls check? the error line i updated for problem line. if(isset($_POST['updateform']))
    {

    **$id=$_REQUEST['id'];**   -> problem line

Comment: I don't know what is `updateform` but , if you are sending data by clicking on `a` tag then it will `GET` request and you have use both `POST` as well in your php code . If you can add more details in your question about `updateform` it would be more clear for us to identify error.

Comment: @Swati Updateform is submit button name.

Comment: so how `id` is pass to backend code ? you have form ?

Comment: @swati there is no seperate form. i can pass id for the same page.

Comment: You are passing data using submit button there is no id which is getting passed so simply put hidden input inside your form tag with value of `id` i.e : `<input type="hidden" name="id" value ="<?php echo $ord_id; ?>">` and try again.

Comment: @Swati  Thanks for that clue. i forgot it that thing! thanks for your support once again swathi :)

Comment: @Swati it seems working now :)